# Sending SMS through intents causes app to stop

Tags: android, sms, send

I have been trying to create an app that sends an image to another person, only an image. One of the layouts of the app has a text field for if the user wants to manually type in the answer, and two buttons: one to search in the contacts so the user can pick a contact, and one to send the message. The send button is supposed to ensure that there is input in the text field before if attempts to send. I found a way to send texts that seemed much simpler than the other ways I had found. I'm new to android development. The way I used below is through intents. It doesn't have the picture part added in yet because I wanted to make sure it worked first, so it just sends hello world. It doesn't appear to have any bugs in the program, but when I press the send button, an error shows up which says that the app had to stop. Do you guys know what I should do to fix it? I've cleaned a few times. Thank you for your help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Send extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText phoneNo = null;
    String phoneNoString;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);

        // Set up click listener for all buttons
        View sendSmsButton = findViewById(R.id.send_sms_button);
        sendSmsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View contactsButton = findViewById(R.id.contacts);
        contactsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.send_sms_button:
            phoneNoString = phoneNo.getEditableText().toString().trim();
            invokesSMSApp();
        }
    }

    public void invokesSMSApp() {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello World!");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNoString);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

        startActivity(smsIntent);
    }
}
```

These are the errors I received:

```
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.example.getaroundtoit.Send.onClick(Send.java:31)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 00:56:09.213: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 00:56:16.835: E/Trace(1131): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.example.getaroundtoit.Send.onClick(Send.java:31)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 00:59:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The emulator gives an error message on the emulator screen that says the app had to stop.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
EditText phoneNo = null;
```

and then you are calling:

```
phoneNoString = phoneNo.getEditableText().toString().trim();
```

but the phoneNo is null and here is the problem. It seems you are missing something like this in the onCreate method:

```
phoneNo = (EditText)findViewById(<pnoneNo ID goes here>);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @lonelyminstrel Accepting the answer as the correct one will help me and other people when they see this post. Thank you...